# Is there a ms sql setting that allows value != null to be true

Tags: sql-server

in MS SQL I have come accross a query like below:

```
select Wubba, Dubba
from Dub as dub
where Dubba != 10
```

When `Dubba` is null, the select returns zero rows. Since im looking for a bug, I was wondering if there a setting in MS SQL that would allow this query to return values.

Comment: SQL works off of the three-valued logic. true, false, null. By design. If your 'bug' is causing Non-nulls to enter on null values...well,that is one heckava bug that is utterly crippling your RDBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no setting which provides the behaviour you are looking for..you can try below

```
Dubba != 10 or dubba is null
```

Using `ISNULL(somecol,val)` is not [Sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

there is a setting called [SET ANSI_NULLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188048.aspx) ,but this won't work in comparisons

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, a *SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name = NULL returns zero rows even if there are null values in column_name*
>
> When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, *A SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name = NULL returns the rows that have null values in column_name*

When `SET ANSI_NULLS is ON` Null <> Null
When `SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF` Null = Null

But you are asking to include nulls ,if the column has NULL values,only way to get nulls is, to specify

Further reading from [Itzik Ben-Gan](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/):

[Don’t Avoid the UNKNOWN](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/don-t-avoid-unknown)
[Predicate-Based Query Filters](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/predicate-based-query-filters)

Answer (score 2):

Seems there is no setting, so you can use:

```
select Wubba, Dubba
from Dub as dub
where ISNULL(Dubba, 0) != 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Wubba, Dubba
from Dub as dub
where Dubba != 10 Or Dubba Is Null
```

As there is no server setting